# Hibernate: how to set relations (annotations) in a more complex model?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, jpa-2.0

I have the following simplified model:

```
Business - (1:n) - Assignment - (n:1) - Process
```

The model classes have the following annotation:

**Business**

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "business", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Assignment> assignments;
```

**Assignment**

normally one would avoid creating a separate model class here, because Business and Process have a n:m relation. But I need to add attributes to Assigment itself.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "business_id")
private Business business;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "process_id")
private Process process;
```

**Process**

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "process", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Assignment> assignments;
```

*Requirements*

1. When a Business or Process is deleted, I also want all his Assignments deleted (but not the partner of the relation on @OneToMany side)
2. When an Assignment is deleted, I do not want to remove both @OneToMany sides (either Business or Process)

*Hints*

- I tried this with `orphanRemoval = true` and without, but got no complete sufficient solution
- The model classes inherit from a MappedSuperClass which provides Identifier
- The `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)` was needed because I have several `@OneToMany` relations in a Business and Process but this annotation does not relate to this issue
- I use H2 as database and only work with Spring's @Repository interfaces when interacting with persistance layer so not a single line of SQL is written

---

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately I thought that the endorsement of following annotation:
`@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)` 
and JUnit test approves correct working of desired behaviour hence answered my question.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    // stores an Business object in db and returns the saved object
    Business b = createBusiness();
    // stores an Process object in db and returns the saved object
    Process p = createProcess();
    // stores Assignmnent object with both relations in db and returns the saved object
    Assignment a = createAssignment(b, p);
    assertThat(a).isNotNull();
    // deletes Process object from db
    processService.delete(p);
    assertThat(processService.getById(p.getId())).isNull();
    assertThat(assignmentService.getById(a.getId())).isNull();
    assertThat(businessService.getById(b.getId())).isNotNull();
}
```

But this is not the case. In my JavaFX application the deletion is logged and it looks like its working, but when querying the database afterwards, the entity is still in the table although in the JUnit test it is not...
If anybody could bring some light in this issue I would be very thankful.

*If any further information is needed, I will provide it, of course. Thank you very much in advance for helping me out.*

Comment: Does it happen that an assignment is linked to both a business and a process? (I assume yes and that it's actually an N:M relation between business and process)

Comment: @Gimby: You're right, we have a n:m between the Business and the Process. The Assignment table is used because I needed to add attributes to Assignment itself. _(Added this information to the description)_

Comment: Well then I can guess you're deleting a process and expecting the assignments to magically be cascade deleted. Except - they're not orphaned. They still belong to a business.

Comment: So it is not possible to give this to Hibernate? **I.e. I have to delete one side** (either Business -> Assignment or Process -> Assignment) **by myself, if an Assignment has a Business and a Process**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**
Finally I have solved the issue and got my desired behaviour with the following setup:

**Business**

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "business", orphanRemoval = true)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private List<Assignment> assignments;
```

**Assignment**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "business_id")
private Business business;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "process_id")
private Process process;
```

**Process**

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "process", orphanRemoval = true)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private List<Assignment> assignments;
```

---

Please take note of the added annotation `@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)`. This hint came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10915358/4135367). I omitted Hibernate docs here, because they (imho) do not provide additional useful informations about the feature than the linked SO post.

**Update**:
Also consider the removed `cascade` attribute, which was not necessary because I am using hibernates `@OnDelete`.

Comment: Do note that this is Hibernate specific and thus not a JPA solution.